# Django - How do I use UserChangeForm my in web-app?

Tags: django, django-admin

When I tried to modify the current entry with UserChangeForm in my page, it says "User is already existed". But the I had no problem modifying the entry through the admin portal.

model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    users = (
        ('doctor', 'Doctor'),
        ('patient', 'Patient'),
        ('assistant', 'Assistant'),
    )

    user_type = models.CharField(choices=users, max_length=9, default='patient')

    #return the users' name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name  + " " + self.last_name

class Doctor(models.Model):
    upin = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #unique physician identification number
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user.user_type = "doctor"
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    appointments_per_hour = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    #return the doctors' name
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

forms.py

```
class DoctorForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('user','specialty','appointments_per_hour',)
```

Comment: You're trying to change the `Doctor` model, don't subclass `UserChangeForm`, just use a normal `ModelForm`.

Comment: When I tried to user ModelForm it gives me the same error. Wouldn't it make sense that I use ChangeForm if I'm updating the info instead of adding a new doctor?

Comment: No, a ModelForm handles both changes to an existing instance (you initialise it with `instance=doctor`) or creating new instances (if you don't pass it `instance` at initialisation). You should show us the entire error you get and show us the view.

Comment: `class AddDoctor(generic.CreateView): `

      `form_class = DoctorForm `

      `success_url = reverse_lazy('index') `

      `template_name ='registration/add_doctor.html'`

I'm only usings views to generate the form page.